# Expo EAS Build Failed - Starting from Xcode 14, resource bundles are signed by default

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, eas

I have been trying to run my application after switching to EAS. However face the issue below

**Error Message**

```
 iOS build failed:
Starting from Xcode 14, resource bundles are signed by default, which requires 
setting the development team for each resource bundle target.
To resolve this issue, downgrade to an older Xcode version using the "image" field in 
eas.json, or turn off signing resource bundles in your Podfile: 
https://expo.fyi/r/disable-bundle-resource-signing
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/#ios-build-server- 
configurations
```

I have read that most poeple are making a change to their Podfile as a bypass for this issue, just to get their applications running. Is there a better solution to avoid this problem? I am running Ventura and cannot install an older version of xcode due to compatibility.

**Podfile**

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")
#  install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false


platform :ios, '13.0'

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read('./Podfile.properties.json')) rescue {}

target 'myreactnativeapp' do
  use_modular_headers!
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes'
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!('Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1')
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    # Workaround `Cycle inside FBReactNativeSpec` error for react-native 0.64
    # Reference: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/842#issuecomment-812543933
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end

end
```